# Detecting if inputs match by having common elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input boxes and I am trying to compare them, in order to see if they have common elements. For some reason, though, it is not working. My code:

HTML:

```html
Personal Address line 1: <input type = "text" id = "persAdd1" />
Address Line 1: <input type = "text" id = "addLine1" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Continue" onclick = "vali()" />
```

JavaScript:

```js
function vali() {
    var add1Str = document.getElementById('persAdd1').value;
    var add2Str = document.getElementById('addLine1').value;
    var arr1 = add1Str.split(" ");
    var arr2 = add2Str.split(" ");
    var arr3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
                arr3.push( arr1[i] );
                if(arr3 !== ""){
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stelios13/u4fAD/1/)**

Any ideas?

Comment: `matches` is undefined.

Comment: Your spliiting add1Str twice ? is ther an reason for that?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Just changed it, but still not working.

Comment: where did you changed? what exactly `matches` variable contains? it is not defined

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a typo. I'm pushing matching elements into arr3 (if one found) and then I check whether is empty or not. If yes, I throw an alert message

Comment: do you want to alert if empty or if not empty? you are now throwing `error` alert if not empty

Comment: Yeap, exactly. If arr3 is not empty, then I alert the user that has entered 2 similar addresses

Comment: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/u4fAD/3/) your requirement?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much Harry. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below would work for you.

```
function vali() {
    var add1Str = document.getElementById('persAdd1').value;
    var add2Str = document.getElementById('addLine1').value;
    var arr1 = add1Str.split(" ");
    var arr2 = add2Str.split(" ");
    var arr3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
                arr3.push(arr1[i]);
                //console.log(arr3);
            }
        }
    }
    if (arr3.length > 0) { //check if the array 3 has any items, if yes alert error.
        alert("error");
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/u4fAD/3/)

Comment: Thanks again. So the mistake was at my last if statement

Comment: Yes. For checking if an array has any item, you can use the `.length` of the array. Also, I moved the check to be outside the `for` loops because if it is within the loops, it will alert as many times as there are matches.